# Ubuntu configure wxwidgets always gives error 'The development files for GTK+ were not found.'

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

It always reports the same error when I was running ./configure .

And it doesn't check any of my other packages.

I read a lot of discussions on the Internet But none of them would solve my problem.

Configure couldn't find the gtk anyway.

This is the error information.

```
./configure --with-regex=builtin --with-gtk --enable-unicode --disable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/wxWidgets

checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for toolkit... gtk
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the Intel C compiler... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether we are using the Intel C++ compiler... no
checking whether we are using the Sun C++ compiler... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for cxxabi.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking size of short... 2
checking size of void *... 8
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking size of size_t... 8
checking size of long long... 8
checking size of wchar_t... 4
checking for va_copy... yes
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... 64
checking if large file support is available... yes
checking for _LARGEFILE_SOURCE value needed for large files... no
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for std::wstring in <string>... yes
checking for std::istream... yes
checking for std::ostream... yes
checking for type_traits... yes
checking for __sync_xxx_and_fetch builtins... yes
checking for libraries directories... /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib
checking for cos... no
checking for floor... no
checking if floating point functions link without -lm... no
checking for sin... yes
checking for ceil... yes
checking if floating point functions link with -lm... yes
checking for strtoull... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking whether pcre submodule exists... yes
checking for zlib.h >= 1.1.4... yes
checking for zlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for deflate in -lz... yes
checking for png.h > 0.90... yes
checking for png.h... (cached) yes
checking for png_sig_cmp in -lpng... yes
checking for jpeglib.h... yes
checking for jpeg_read_header in -ljpeg... yes
checking for jbg_dec_init in -ljbig... yes
checking for LIBTIFF... yes
checking for expat.h... yes
checking if expat.h is valid C++ header... yes
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... yes
checking for LIBCURL... yes
checking for GTK+ version... 
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for GTK+ - version >= 3.0.0... no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occurred. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.7... yes
checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.6.0... no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for GTK+ - version >= 3.90.0... Package gtk4 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk4.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk4' found
no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occurred. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
checking for gtk-config... no
checking for GTK - version >= 1.2.7... no
*** The gtk-config script installed by GTK could not be found
*** If GTK was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the GTK_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to gtk-config.
checking for gtk-config... (cached) no
checking for GTK - version >= 1.2.3... no
*** The gtk-config script installed by GTK could not be found
*** If GTK was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the GTK_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to gtk-config.
configure: error: 
The development files for GTK+ were not found. For GTK+ 2, please
ensure that pkg-config is in the path and that gtk+-2.0.pc is
installed. For GTK+ 1.2 please check that gtk-config is in the path,
and that the version is 1.2.3 or above. Also check that the
libraries returned by 'pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs' or 'gtk-config
--libs' are in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH or equivalent.
```

I download every packages about gtk But it still didn't work .

Comment: Reading instructions on the Internet is fine, but you should really start by reading the instructions right in front of you: `The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the exact error that occurred.`. If you looked at `config.log`, you would have immediately seen the reason of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the "dev" packages of gtk ?
Try the foillowing :

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
```

Regards
Xav'